# Loading next image inside popup Div

Tags: php, sql, image, mysqli

I'm just wondering how social media website adds a link into there popups on there first image to load the next new image into the the same popup div.

I have the first image in my pop up and as you can see I tried using a different page to load in where all the functionality works.

```
<?  if($user2_id==$_SESSION['id']){ 
$cover="SELECT coverphoto_id,coverphoto from coverphotos WHERE coverphoto_userid='$user1_id'";
$rescover=mysqli_query($mysqli,$cover) or die(mysqli_error($mysqli));
$rowcover=mysqli_fetch_assoc($rescover);
?>
    <script>
    function popup(){
        $("#popUpDiv").load('include/covermedia.userimage.php?pid=<? echo $rowcover['coverphoto_id'] ?>');
        $("#blanket").show();
        $("#popUpDiv").show();
    }
    </script>
    <div id="blanket" style="display:none"></div>
    <div id="popUpDiv" style="display:none">

    <a href="#" onClick="popup('popUpDiv')" >X</a>

    </div>

    <a href="#" onClick="popup('popUpDiv')" ><div id="usercover" >
    <? echo "<img id=\"coverimage\" border=\"0\" src='coverimages/".$rowcover['coverphoto']."?".time()."' width=\"600px\"  onerror='this.src=\"coverimages/nocover.png\"' alt='onerror='this.style.height='300px'>";
    ?>
```

Problem I'm facing is that the previous and next links in the loaded page don't load the next new data inside the popup div, they navigate to the page.

```
`include/covermedia.userimage.php?pid=".$photo_prev['coverphoto_id']."'`
```

Is there any simple way I could achieve this.. even by not having to load a page into the popup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you're changing page locations, which it sounds like you are, put an iframe where you have the div (or inside your div) and change the iframe src to your new URL:

```
$("#popUpIFrame").attr('src','include/covermedia.userimage.php?pid=<? echo $rowcover['coverphoto_id'] ?>');
```

Comment: ooo Fantastic. I must admit I was looking around and thought it had something to do with Iframe. Thank you for your help.